# Issues when checkout a branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have an issue when I try to checkout a branch.

I see the branch file in logs/refs/ but cannot checkout on it.
It happend that when I was commiting my changes into it, the power was cut off and when it came back I was not on the branch and I cannot checkout again.

running `git branch` does not show the branch.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to see what your changes were recently. Alternatively, if you can look at the file and resolve it to a hash, you can do `git reset --hard <hash>` to bring it back, or `git checkout -b look <hash>` if you want to check it out to a new branch to see what's going on.